# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skimage' when already installed new version scikit-image

Tags: scikit-image, modulenotfounderror

I want to ask that I face the problem:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skimage'
even though I have already pip3 install scikit-image.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vop5C.png)
my version is Python 3.7.2
and when typing pip3 list, the version is:
scikit-image          0.17.2

Does any one know how to solve this problem?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

scikit-image and scikit-learn are two different packages. The latest scikit-image version is 0.17.2. Are you sure you have installed scikit-image?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry for the typo . Yes i have installed scikit-image and the version is 0.17.2

Comment: Good-oh! The next question is how you are launching your code. It's very common, for example, to install scikit-image in one environment that doesn't have jupyter or ipython, and then try to do some analysis in either of those tools that are in fact being launched from a *different* Python environment.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just realized that there are two environment of my python3 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3 and I found that when I type python3 -m pip install, the scikit image will be installed in the right environment.

Answer (score 0):

It also depends wether you are on a Anaconda plateform or a local python platform in your computer (c:\User....). If python is installed directly in your computer outside Anaconda, this error may occur when importing the scikit-image library. In such case, you should re-install the scikit-image library from the Anaconda plateform by typing the command 'conda install scikit-image' from the Ananconda prompt or terminal.